# How can I pass a request to the server inside the filter and return what return the server in Vue js?

Tags: vuejs2

For example this filter. I use this filter for translating my text.

```
Vue.filter('translate', function (value, lang) {
  let text = ''
  Vue.http.post('admin-api/site/translate', {
    text: value,
    lang: lang
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }, response => console.log(response)).then(response => {
    text = response.text
  })
  return text
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5217